# Stage 2 MemAttr Long Descriptor ARM PTE query

Tags: arm

For Stage 2 Translation, there is a field in lower attributes called MemAttr[3:0]
Exhaustively enumerating its all possible values gives the following table

```
    /* All Possible Values of MemAttr for Stage 2 */
/*
 *  0000    Region is Strongly Ordered
 *  0001    Device Memory   [ONC by Default]
 *  0010    XXXXX
 *  0011    XXXXX
 *  0100    XXXXX
 *  0101    Normal Memory O   NC, I NC
 *  0110    Normal Memory O   NC, I WT C
 *  0111    Normal Memory O   NC, I WB C
 *  0100    XXXXX
 *  1001    Normal Memory O WT C, I NC
 *  1010    Normal Memory O WT C, I WT C
 *  1011    Normal Memory O WT C, I WB C
 *  1100    XXXXX
 *  1101    Normal Memory O WB C, I NC
 *  1110    Normal Memory O WB C, I WT C
 *  1111    Normal Memory O WB C, I WB C
 */
```

O - Outer
I - Inner
WB- WriteBack
WT- WriteThrough
NC - Non Cacheable
C - Cacheable.

Now I am wondering for normal memory assigned to guest, what should be the values I should put in mem attr. I am only looking for WriteBack Cacheable.

Answer (score 2):

Normal, write-back cacheable is what you want for any general-purpose RAM mappings. Unless you're doing something very special, you want that for both inner and outer caches.