# What are the benefits/uses of Device or Strongly-ordered memory type?

Tags: arm, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, cortex-m

My question is regarding different memory types available on an M-4 chip which I am reading about right now. To summarize, there are three different types of memory, i.e. 'normal', 'device' and 'strongly-ordered' that define the sequence (or whether there will be any sequence at all) in which memory system will carry out program instructions (e.g. ldr or str). It seems that 'normal' memory type allows memory system to move instruction execution order around to improve efficiency, provided that program behaviour is unchanged.

The question is - if the behaviour is unchanged and efficiency is improved, what are the practical uses of 'device' and 'strongly-ordered' memory. From my beginner perspective, I understand that there must be a reason for them to exist, but I am yet to have personal experience to link to this topic.

Comment: Does [arm cortex-m barrier page](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0321a/BIHGGAIE.html) answer your questions?  Some hw-devices only handle a certain access; ie a single 32bit read/write at a time.  Also, for hw peripherals, the order can be extremely important.  For a person only using normal 'RAM' the other types don't matter.  It is only when the address range is backed by a non-RAM device that it matters.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676562/arm-cortexadifference-between-strongly-ordered-and-device-memory-type

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you use strongly-ordered attribute for memory accesses which have side effects - e.g. FIFOs