# When is a Cortex write to a device realised

Tags: arm, embedded, race-condition, latency, cortex-m

When writing to device registers on a Cortex M0 (in my case, on an STM32L073), a question arises as to how careful one should be in a) ordering accesses to device memory and b) deciding that a change to a peripheral configuration has actually completed to the point that any dependencies become valid.

Taking a specific example to change the internal voltage regulator to a different voltage. You write the change to PWR->CR and read the status from PWR->CSR. I see code that does something like this:

```
Write to PWR->CR to set the voltage range
Spin until (PWR->CSR & voltage flag) becomes zero
```

In my mind there are three issues here:

1. Access ordering. This is Device Memory so transaction order is preserved relative to other Device access transactions. I would assume this means a DSB is not required between the write to CR and the read from CSR. A linked question and the answer to this is: [[ARM CortexA]Difference between Strongly-ordered and Device Memory Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676562/arm-cortexadifference-between-strongly-ordered-and-device-memory-type)
2. Device memory can be buffered. Is there a possibility that a write to CR could still be in process when the read from CSR occurs. This would mean that the voltage flag would be clear and the code would proceed. In actual fact the flag hasn't gone high yet!
3. Hardware response time. Is there a latency between the write and the effects becoming final? In actuality this should always be documented - for the STM32 the docs definitively say that the flag is set when the CR register changes.

Are there any race condition possibilities here? It's really the buffering that worries me - that a peripheral write is still in progress when a peripheral read takes place.

Comment: I assume these are theoretical worries, or have you got a concrete example of something that doesn't work "as expected"?

Comment: If 1/2/3 is an issue I'd expect it to be heavily documented, otherwise interaction with most peripherals would be buggy in pretty much every example (and while manufacturers examples for STM32 are far from the best, described issues would make them pretty much worthless).

Comment: There are cases where either the st docs or their code indicate that you need to read or poll to confirm, often with things that take time outside code execution, analog items like messing with the clocks.  it is certainly possible for a vendor to have design issues for whatever reason, performance, etc, that can cause race conditions a read passing a write so a read-modify-write doesnt work, etc...but as mentioned if the vendor doesnt document these things be it the main docs or errata, then they will likely feel the pain from that as users fall into that trap. Not heard about problems yet.

Comment: from the cortex-ms perspective once the other side has acked the address and data it is no longer a cortex-m problem and can move on.  writes can be fire and forget and from that axi/ahb bus perspective can complete on that bus long before reaching the target, where reads require reaching the target and coming back.  This is nothing new but your title question, the cortex realizes it when the address and data are acked.  From the target perspective depends on the target and the path to target within that chip implementation.

Comment: It's mainly based on experience with the PIC16 where there, for example, a write to serial transmit buffer doesn't clear the TXIF flag immediately. But that's a documented hardware latency issue. As you say, if these things didn't work as described, it would result in users faling into traps! Which makes it perhaps a theoretical worry!

Comment: I was really trying to understand how the peripheral write occurs from the Cortex documentation and the difference between "non-cacheable" yet also "can be buffered". What old_timer said above suddenly makes sense - if the write to the target is acked well the Cortex is done; it's up to the target to keep things straight. What I'd guess is that sequential accesses to *different* peripherals (or normal memory for that matter) have no guarantees at all and would require memory barriers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Access ordering.

Accesses are strongly ordered and you do not need barrier instructions to read back the same register.

> Device memory can be buffered. Is there a possibility that a write to CR

Yes, it is possible. But it is not because of buffering but because of the bus propagation time. It may take several clocks before a particular operation will go through all bridges.

> Hardware response time. Is there a latency between the write and the
> effects becoming final

Even if there is a latency it is not important from your point of view. If you set bit in the CR register and wait for the result in the status register. Simply wait for the status bit to have the expected value.

Comment: That answer makes sense along with what @old_timer has said in the OP comments. I don't think I really appreciated that the ARM devices really are like having a CPU and external peripherals on a bus. That's sounds trite but my previous experience with PIC and Atmel throws me a little because they are more tightly core-integrated. In other words, the PIC can say "a write to the serial port will complete on this cycle and return on this cycle" whereas the ARM will say "a write to a peripheral completes when it acks". Which is slightly different :-)

Comment: @carveone Practically it makes no difference. Core is not only one controller and it has to be on the bus (for example for DMA). Only very simple architecures with limited functionality can be designed as small PICs or AVR uCs.

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly true! I was taking the obsessive-compulsive approach where I read the documentation and think "what trap am I missing here". It was the words "writes to Device memory can be buffered" that kicked all this off. Thanks :-)

Comment: @carveone do not worry. It is not Microchip with errata pages longer than actual programming manual :). You do not have to worry about it at all. I use STM ARM for many years and I am more than happy.